# How to correct a 404 error when I fetch Data from DataBase?

Tags: node.js

I want to fetch data from SQL server using Redis-Caching , but when I send the request
(GET http://localhost:4000/product/Data)    =>     I see this error:

```
                GET /product/Data 404 7.390 ms - 33
                GET /product/Data - - ms - -
```

, How can I solve it ?

server.js :

```
   const redis = require("redis");
   const redisUrl='redis://127.0.0.1:6379'; 
   // create Redis client on Redis port
   const client = redis.createClient(redisUrl);
   //  create express application instance

   const Data=async(req,res,next)=>{
   cache,getData
   }
   //Make request to DataBase for Data 
async function getData(req,res,next){
            try{
            console.log('Fetching Data From SQL server...')
            const Pull_Products=await 
            SingletonSqlHandler.instance.sendQuery('SELECT * from 
            dbo.getAllProducts()')        
            // return Pull_Products;
            return res.status(200).send.json(Pull_Products)
            }
            catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({error:error})
            }
           }
          // Cache midleware
          async function cache(req,res,next){
               console.log('Fetching Data From Cache...')
               const Pull_Products=await 
               SingletonSqlHandler.instance.sendQuery('SELECT * from 
               dbo.getAllProducts()')        
               client.get(Pull_Products,(error,cachedData)=>{
               if(error) throw error
               if(cachedData!=null){
                    res.send(setResponse(Pull_Products,cachedData));
                }
              else {
                     next();
               }
              })
           }
          module.exports={
           Data:Data
          }
```

productRoute.js:

```
      const router = require('express').Router();
      const Redis=require('../redis-cache/server')
      router.get('/Data', Redis.Data);
      module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where have you got the path /product/Data? Shouldn't it be /Data? Unless theres code not included.

Comment: @Isolated  edit it .,I put productRoute.js

Comment: You're using `router.get('/Data');` unless you've then used the router and mounted it, creating a group of subroutes, you'll need to access /Data using a get method. Otherwise you'll recieve 404. Which is not found, incase you didn't know. It may be easier to also include where your routes are declared as I could be wrong (limited information to go off).